# How do I change the default shell used in Byobu (tmux)?

Tags: byobu, tmux

I've become addicted to Byobu and I've recently shifted from bash to zsh; Now I want to combine the two, however I have a one initial pre-requisite:

I cannot make zsh the default shell for my user as it's a shared account and the rest of the team aren't as zsh happy as I am - That rules out the 'chsh -s /bin/zsh' option.

So, I discovered you can set a default-shell for tmux (which should follow across to byobu right?). That would be perfect as I'm also the only one really using Byobu on the server.

Problem is, I can't work out where to enable this option in the confusion of config files that's created in the tmux/byobu mix.

Any hints?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Put the following in your `$HOME/.byobu/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-shell /usr/bin/zsh
set -g default-command /usr/bin/zsh
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thanks Dustin, I'm always super impressed that you hang around here!

It's was the 'set -g default-command' bit I was missing in the end.. I didn't realise you needed the second configuration parameter for it to work.

Comment: No problem ;-)  It's 1000x more useful when someone asks a good question like this, here in AskUbuntu or StackExchange, so that others can benefit from the answer :-)  I just wish I could get all of the people who use IRC and Launchpad Questions over here...

Comment: I found that this loads two shells of the desired type, one clobbering the other. Setting just `default-shell` results in bash clobbering the shell I'm trying to set, but setting `default-command` results in exactly one of the desired shells being started. I guess having the same shell clobber itself is fine, but this could incur a bit of a start time hit as some shells take a while longer to start.

Comment: Is it possible to run a command instead? For example, will `set -g default-shell sudo su` work?

Comment: Why not the `byobu-select-backend` command?

Comment: Note that the settings file may be `~/.config/byobu/.tmux.conf`, depending how your linux is configured.

Comment: `export SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh; byobu`   @Dev

Answer (score 1):

For me, Dustin's solution didn't seem to take at first.

I used to have a working setup where `gnome-terminal` launched `zsh` as a login shell, which then launched `byobu` with my window (split) setup and a couple of `zsh` instances in there. After a distro reinstall, the shell instances in the splits were suddenly `bash`, for whatever reason, even with the above fix.

Whenever I launched `zsh` in those splits I'd get a message from `oh-my-zsh` that a plugin was missing.

I installed the missing package for the plugin and configured it correctly, and now all stages of the setup execute correctly. I suspect that the error message from the sourcing process within `oh-my-zsh` may have caused a fallback to `bash` (possibly within `tmux`?).