# Byobu doesn't pick up my default shell

Tags: command-line, byobu

With the update to 14.10 my byobu setup broke. Apparently now I cannot `exec` during my simple shell configuration script, and I have instead to invoke the exec in the "login shell configuration" (I'm mentioning this, since it could be related to the issue).

After changing how I'm `exec`ing byobu, I realized that byobu doesn't launch my default shell anymore (`/usr/bin/fish`, which for comparison is picked up just fine by gnome-terminal)

I even tried to [manually force the shell selection for tmux](https://askubuntu.com/a/296388/36052), but that doesn't work either.

Any idea?