# How to change the default shell used in Byobu without changing user shell?

Tags: byobu, zsh

I've been using

```
set -g default-shell /usr/bin/zsh
set -g default-command /usr/bin/zsh
```

in my `~/.byobu/.tmux.config` for several years to set the shell that Byobu uses without changing (`chsh`) my login shell, as explained in 
[How do I change the default shell used in Byobu (tmux)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296377/how-do-i-change-the-default-shell-used-in-byobu-tmux) by @Dustin Kirkland, the author and maintainer of Byobu.

I installed Byobu on a new machine from the PPA (currently version 5.92) and this setting does not have any effect. Byobu uses the user shell (`bash` in my case). I've checked and `zsh` is indeed in `/usr/bin/`. How can I determine why this setting is not picked up by Byobu?